# SQL ExecuteReader() Error - VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, executereader

So I'm trying to read and display all entrys from the MDB file with the status as 2 and I keep getting this error:

An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code

When I take out the Where status = 2 it works fine but I need the where in there.

```
<script runat="server">
sub Page_Load
        Dim dataconnector, strSQL, datacommand, dataread
        dataconnector = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Server.MapPath("cgiclass.mdb"))
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE status = 2"
        dataconnector.Open()
        datacommand = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, dataconnector)
        dataread = datacommand.ExecuteReader()
        suppliers.DataSource = dataread
        suppliers.DataBind()
        dataread.Close()
        dataconnector.Close()
    End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: What is the data type of `suppliers.status`?

Comment: Maybe status is a string and not a number. If this is the case, use `... WHERE status = '2'`

Comment: Add a `Try/Catch` and see what the exception is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx

Comment: @Arman I feel stupid now haha. Thanks a lot man that got it to work.